# Ansible templating with special characters

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following Ansible variable:

```yaml
environment:
  CONFIG: |
    external_url 'https://www.example.com'
    external_port '9090'
  USERNAME: root
  ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
```

Ansible template file:

```yaml
environment:
{% for key, value in environment.items() %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output should be:

```yaml
environment:
  CONFIG: |
    external_url 'https://www.example.com'
    external_port '9090'
  USERNAME: root
  ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
```

But the output is:

```yaml
environment:
  CONFIG: external_url 'https://www.example.com'
external_port '9090'

  USERNAME: root
  ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
```

It seems the `|` character is not literally used. It also breaks the indentation. Which filter should I use in my template?

**Added my playbook and more since it was asked for:**

template.j2:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    docker_compose_projects:
       - name: project_1
         services:
           - service_name: some_service
             image: some_image:latest
             environment:
               CONFIG: |
                 external_url 'https://www.example.com'
                 external_port '9090'
               USERNAME: root
               ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
  tasks:
    - name: template
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: template.yml.j2
        dest: "/home/username/{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ docker_compose_projects }}"
```

template.yml.j2:

```
services:
{% for service in item.services %}
  {{ service.service_name }}
    image: {{ service.image }}
{% if service.environment is defined %}
  environment:
{% for key, value in service.environment.items() %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Output (project_1):

```yaml
services:
  some_service:
    image: some_image:latest
    environment:
      CONFIG: external_url 'https://www.example.com'
external_port '9090'

      USERNAME: root
      ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
```

Expected output:

```yaml
services:
  some_service:
    image: some_image:latest
    environment:
      CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://www.example.com'
        external_port '9090'
      USERNAME: root
      ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret
```

Comment: "_It seems the `|` character is not literally used. It also breaks the indentation._", It is used, but not in the way you assume. Therefore the current result is the expected one. See [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/6771046) for the reason.

Comment: `The output should be:...` <= well actually not and what you get is in fact precisely what you asked for. Please see https://yaml-multiline.info/. Also, please delete the two other questions you opened by mistake which where marked as duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator I was not aware of the duplicate posts, I deleted them. I need the `|` character in my output, so it should write that character instead of interpreting it as a multi-line/block.

Comment: @C-nan, "_was not aware of the duplicate posts_", right, it looked like a glitch as all were opened identical almost at the same time.

Comment: "_I need the | character in my output, so it should write that character instead of interpreting it as a multi-line/block._", can you show your playbook? Can you show how or where the variables become defined? Can you show also your template task? With the current information it's not that easy to write a reproducible example up.

Comment: Furthermore, `environment` is a [Playbook Keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) which can't be used an own [valid variable name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).

Comment: @U880D I have added some code to my original post.

Comment: @C-nan, where are the `vars` coming from? Are they defined (hard-coded) within the playbook? Are they from a file? Do you have control about the data structure, means is it possible to change the data structure?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use group_vars files or something like that and copy the config YAML files?

Comment: @U880D The vars are in host_vars files. Some hosts will have the `CONFIG |` part and some not. Some hosts won't even have the `environment` part. I can use copy instead of template, but if possible I would like to use template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256447/discussion-between-c-nan-and-u880d).

Comment: @C-nan, based on your last comment it seems for me even the data structure is incoherent. With the currently available information and examples I am not able to create anything useful. Maybe someone else can provide an answer or some insights here. Meanwhile you could take advantage from [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/394576) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), step back and ovethink what you are really try to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A bit of explanation

You need to put `|` to the template itself to keep the multiline formatting, and render the lines of multiline strings in a nested loop:

```py
{{ key }}: |
  {% for line in value.splitlines() %}
  {{ line }}
  {% endfor %}
```

But since your variables could be both single-line and multiline, you will have to keep a default option, too:

```py
    {% for key, value in service.environment.items() %}
    {% if '\n' in value %}
      {{ key }}: |
        {% for line in value.splitlines() %}
        {{ line }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

You will also have to manually [control the whitespaces](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#whitespace-control). Given that your template already has different indents for keys of the same level, it will be *hard* to achieve that individually for each block. To keep the template readable and editable, you can set `#jinja2: lstrip_blocks:True, trim_blocks:True` globally, and maintain the desired indentation within the template directly (see the next chapter).

#### Correct template

It probably could be optimized and beautified further, but I think it's enough to show the idea. Note that I also fixed some syntax problems of your original template such as missed `:` after `{{ service.service_name }}` and unquoted image name:

```py
#jinja2: lstrip_blocks:True, trim_blocks:True
---
services:
  {% for service in item.services %}
  {{ service.service_name }}:
    image: "{{ service.image }}"
  {% if service.environment is defined %}
    environment:
    {% for key, value in service.environment.items() %}
    {% if '\n' in value %}
      {{ key }}: |
        {% for line in value.splitlines() %}
        {{ line }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

#### Example

Let's take this simplified playbook as a minimal reproducible example (of course, the variables should reside in group or host vars, and the secrets should be encrypted or injected):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    docker_compose_projects:
      - name: project_1
        services:
          - service_name: some_service_1
            image: "some_image_1:latest"
            environment:
              CONFIG: |
                external_url 'https://www.example.com'
                external_port '9090'
              USERNAME: root
              ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret1
          - service_name: some_service_2
            image: "some_image_2:latest"
            environment:
              USERNAME: root
              ROOT_PASSWORD: verysecret2
          - service_name: some_service_3
            image: "some_image_3:latest"
  tasks:
    - name: Render the template
      template:
        src: template-trimmed.yml.j2
        dest: "target_dir/{{ item.name }}.yml"
      loop: "{{ docker_compose_projects }}"
```

The template from the previous chapter will generate this beatiful YAML file:

```yaml
---
services:
  some_service_1:
    image: "some_image_1:latest"
    environment:
      CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://www.example.com'
        external_port '9090'
      USERNAME: "root"
      ROOT_PASSWORD: "verysecret1"
  some_service_2:
    image: "some_image_2:latest"
    environment:
      USERNAME: "root"
      ROOT_PASSWORD: "verysecret2"
  some_service_3:
    image: "some_image_3:latest"
```